# How to you revert a staged file with changes, preserving the changes to when it was staged?

Tags: git

Say I edited a file

```
echo "hi" > someVersionedFile.txt

//Then I staged the file
git add .
git status

<console reads>
 Changes to be committed
 new file: someVersionedFile.txt
```

Now I make additional changes to the files

```
echo "hi again file" >> someVersionedFile.txt

//Then I restage the file with these changes
git add .
git status

<console reads>
 Changed but not commited
 modified file: someVersionedFile.txt
```

**Question: how do I revert the last staged version? Is this possible to do since it wasn't committed?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but I too would like to know if it is!

Comment: Not sure how you do that, but if you commit now, only the staged changes will be committed. You could then revert that file to the commit you just made.

Comment: @andypaxo That is not the problem. More closely, the problem is, if you stage a file a with changes; make more changes to it, then how do you revert the file back to when it was staged - given there were/are additional changes to the staged file?

Comment: @thatDudeThatDoesThatThing That's the entire point of a commit. You're making a version commitment. You're telling the version control it should keep track of the current status of files. If that helps you - think of git as a graph, when you commit you insert a node to that graph, and you can only travel between nodes (versions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably do this, but there's no single simple command to do it for you.

When you do `git add`, the file has already been added to the repository, but there is currently nothing pointing to it except the index. When you do a second `git add`, the new (version of the) file gets added to the repository, and the link between the index and the first version of the file is replaced with the new link. But the first object is still there.

You can use `git fsck --dangling` to get a list of blob objects in your repository that are currently not referenced by anything, but then you'll have to go through them one by one with `git show`, `git cat-file`, etc. to determine which is the file you want. Once you find the right file, you can `git show HASH > somefile.txt` (and maybe `git add somefile.txt`).

Of course, if you've done any `git prune`, `git gc`, etc. since the second `git add`, that may have actually removed the original file from your repository.

Here's a quick example:

```
$ git init foo
Initialized empty Git repository in foo/.git/
$ cd foo
$ echo blah > foo.txt
$ git add foo.txt
$ echo blarg > foo.txt
$ git add foo.txt
$ git fsck --dangling
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling blob 907b308167f0880fb2a5c0e1614bb0c7620f9dc3
$ git show 907b308167f0880fb2a5c0e1614bb0c7620f9dc3
blah
$
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this.  Git can only revert files to a previous *commit*, not previous staged version.  This is because the file won't be entered into git's repository until you make the commit.  (You can read more about best practices in committing over at [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/check-in-early-check-in-often.html))

Perhaps you can apply judicious use of the `undo` button? (If you've edited the code in an editor, obviously `echo`ing to the file doesn't have an undo).

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to revert back **to** the staged version? Yeah, you can definitely do that. Probably the simplest way is to just commit your staged changes, checkout the file from that commit, and then reset your branch:

```
git commit -m "Temporary commit"
git checkout HEAD -- /path/to/file_you_want_to_revert
git reset HEAD~
```

**Edit: Oops, sorry I didn't notice the part where you restaged the file with the new changes.** Sorry, but the other answers are correct: this isn't possible (or at least, not very easy). I'll leave this answer up, just in case someone else has a similar problem to you but hasn't overwritten the cache yet.

Comment: Although it is the wrong answer, you can achieve the same just by `git checkout /path/to/file_you_want_to_revert` without giving a branch name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - just to word it a different way `git checkout [path]` will **revert** the target file to its staged version, but only if present! If you run the same command on a file that has no stage it will be reverted to its state at the commit. So you could lose work if there isn't a stage you're intending to rollback to :)